# how can i repair this autoclick button script: while(autoscript){buttonName.click()}

Tags: javascript

so i just wanted to make a script to the game that autoclicks button

ive tried using true/false statements but somehow this isnt working

```
var maxa = document.querySelector("#maxall")

var autoscript = false

while(autoscript) {
    maxa.click();
}
```

Comment: `autoscript` is `false`, so the `while` loop never runs. Also, running a click event in an endless loop is probably not a good idea...

Comment: i know about autoscript that is false i just will do this manually by console

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
let clicker = setInterval(() => document.getElementById('maxall').click(), 50);
```

It uses setInterval because an endless while loop could be a little bit too much for the browser to handle. Adjust the number (second parameter of `setInterval()` to change the speed. The number says "on every x ms call this function".

And when you want to stop it again use:

```
clearInterval(clicker);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, your while loop needs to evaluate to true, so change autoscript to true.

Second, if you have control over how this script loads, make sure that it loads after the dom does by including it in the bottom of the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var maxa = document.querySelector("#maxall")

var autoscript = false;

var interval = 1E2; // 0.1 second

toggle();

function toggle() {
  autoscript = !autoscript;
  if (autoscript) {
    var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
      if (autoscript) maxa.click();
      else clearInterval(intervalID);
    }, interval);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="maxall" onclick="console.log('clicked')">Click</button>
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle</button>
```